# Mock window.notification in jest - Error: Property `permission` does not have access type get

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to mick window.Notification in jest, but I receive an error:

```
Error: Property `permission` does not have access type get
```

My setupTests.ts:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

globalThis.Notification = ({
  requestPermission: jest.fn(),
  permission: "granted",
} as unknown) as jest.Mocked<typeof Notification>;
```

and line in test:

```js
    jest
      .spyOn(window.Notification, 'permission', 'get')
      .mockReturnValue('denied');
```

Any ideas what I missed or do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying any `getter` function on property `permission`. You can skip the third argument on `spyOn` method or use it as the example in the documentation:

[Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype)